# Go Command Not Found” Error When Using Sudo

Tags: go, debugging, command

sudo go install github.com/KathanP19/Gxss@latest
sudo: go: command not found

I try to install tool with sudo command but it shows sudo: go: command not found....any solutions?

but i installed go

─(spark㉿usr)-[~]
└─$ go version                                                              1 ⨯
go version go1.18.1 linux/amd64

echo $PATH
/home/spark/.cargo/bin:/home/spark/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/go/bin

Answer (score 37):

sudo has its own $PATH which is defined by the `secure_path` setting in your sudo config.

To fix it:

1. Open your sudo config `sudo visudo`
2. Locate the line staring with `Defaults    secure_path =`
3. Add `:/usr/local/go/bin` to the end of the line

After saving the config, you should be able to use go with sudo